# How to produce an imported object as expected?

Tags: import

I will admit that I am a noob with blender. As 'green' as anyone you can imagine. So if this question is very basic, then I am sorry for bothering.

I have bought a world map asset online. It can be found here: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/space/planet/ultra-high-deffinition-earth

Problem is, when I import the file into my blender, I can only work with a sphere and it looks nothing like what was pictured on the site. I just get a grey sphere without any details. I have uploaded a few characters and did not have an issue with them. I get this:

[image: Sphere no details]

I have tried different files types but always get the same results. Is there another procedure I have to do to get the desire maplike object? Or have I done something wrong? Or some site where I can read up more on the topic?

Thank you all for any help or explanations

Comment: You aren’t viewing it in solid mode, are you? Solid mode by default does not display textures.

Comment: if my answer doesn't help, please provide your blend file. So we can check it out. You can provide blend file by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

in the upper right corner of your viewport ....

[image]

are these buttons here:

[image]

Try to tap the right ones. One is for "rendered" and one for "material preview". This should show it right.

You can see the name/function of the buttons if you hover with the mouse cursor over the button.